# TextView text is changed but not showing

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a textview and when I change the text using `tv.setText("hello");` it changes the text because I check with `'Log.d(TAG, tv.getText());'` but when I run the app the changes don't show up visually. What can be the problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getBundleData();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_sensor_report);

    context = this;


    tempN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_temperature_num);
    tempC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_temperature_cat);
    humidityC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_humidity_cat);


    tempN.setText("" + liveDataNum[0]);
    humidityC.setText("" + liveDataCat[1]);
    Log.d("TAG", ""+humidityC.getText());

    drawGraph();

}
```

XML (Its quite complex):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/sv_liveData">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_temperature_num"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devicecardstatus"

                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_temperature_cat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_humidity_num"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devicecardstatus"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="00" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_humidity_cat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_carbonMonoxide_num"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devicecardstatus"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="00" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_carbonMonoxide_cat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ozone_num"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devicecardstatus"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="00" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_ozone_cat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_sulfurDioxide_num"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/devicecardstatus"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="00" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_sulfurDioxide_cat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_device_historical_report" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxkScLxtYNVdZHVnZ2RVS0x2a1k

Edit: I clean/rebuild and this is what happened:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence$2) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Comment: Please share the code where you use `tv.setText("hello")`

Comment: `but when I run the app the changes don't show up visually` could you share your xml and code please

Comment: please check color code of text tooo may be its white

Comment: where is `tv.setText` ?

Comment: humidityC.setText("" + liveDataCat[1]); check  liveDataCat[1] contains what? and check textcolor also

Comment: @VaibhavJain editted to show code.

Comment: it contains the word "Humidity" @ZakiPathan

Comment: can you please share image/screenshot?

Comment: @SunilChaudhary nope, I have it initially as Lorem ipsum and then I am changing it to "Humidity" but it still says "Lorem ipsum"

Comment: @TirthRami clean-rebuild your ide

Comment: humidityC.setText("" + liveDataCat[1].toString()); try this of this helps. otherwise send screenshot. and try to set humidityC.setText("Humidity"); statically and check first

Comment: @ZakiPathan tried both and again, they both dont show on the device but when I do Log.d(TAG,humidityC.getText().toString()) it shows up correctly. Also here is screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxkScLxtYNVdZHVnZ2RVS0x2a1k

Comment: wait I am trying that myself

Comment: Its working fine for me check my answer

Comment: this is full error log? please post full error code and error is not coming your above posted code. error reflects from somewhere else @TirthRami

Comment: i check your code and find all welll except i find is did you add value   in liveDataCat[0]="hey"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is working properly please check screenshot here]

Please post your full code. I think the problem is something else. your above posted code is correct. But after that which code is implemented? I think that code affect your xml

```
TextView humidityC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_humidity_cat);
        humidityC.setText("Humidity");
        Log.d("TAG", ""+humidityC.getText());
```

Comment: Happy to help you @TirthRami If any other problem occurs will help you :) :) :)

Comment: Hahahahaha but the good part is that its working now. So enjoy @TirthRami